# Equivalent of mongo shell UUID() in java mongo driver

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver

Following query is perfectly working in mongo shell.

```
db.collection.find({ "_id" : UUID("87aa9ed6-8485-4517-8e90-08e521372e9a")})
```

I want to achieve same programmatically in java. I have tried below approaches but not getting any result.

```
1) collection.find(eq("_id", "87aa9ed6-8485-4517-8e90-08e521372e9a"));

2) `UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("87aa9ed6-8485-4517-8e90-08e521372e9a");
collection.find(eq("_id", uuid));`
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this for single UUID if you have a mongoTemplate defined

```
Query query= new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(uuid));
mongoTemplate.findOne(query,YourObjectName.class);
```

If you have multiple UUIDs you can use criteria orOperator

```
Query query= new Query();
Criteria criteria=new Criteria();
List<Criteria> orCriteria=new ArrayList<>();
String[] splitId=ids.split(",");
for(String id:splitId){
     UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(id);
     orCriteria.add(Criteria.where("_id").is(uuid));
  }
criteria.orOperator(orCriteria.toArray(new Criteria[orCriteria.size()]));
query.addCriteria(criteria);
mongoTemplate.find(query,YourObjectName.class);
```

Lmk if that works.